# A question about the emergence of 'spin' from relativistic QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, relativity, dirac-equation

I know that quantum-spin is not equivalent to the spinning of a classical object about an axis passing through it, although there are some similarities.

I also know that spin naturally emerges out of Dirac's equation which was the first equation to incorporate both special relativity and quantum physics. So I was thinking is it possible to develop a different analogy for quantum-spin in terms of classical theories of rotation and special relativity.

Does anyone know of any attempts in this area?

Comment: What do you mean by "different analogy"? By the Einstein-de Haas effect, angular momentum *is* the correct analogy for spin because it *does behave like a form of angular momentum*, it just isn't associated to anything actually rotating. What are "classical theories of rotation"?

Comment: "classical rotation" means something rotating. I was wondering whether qm spin can be related to some relativistic corrections to actual rotation or something similar. The fact that spin is "born" out of Dirac eqn seems to suggest that.

Comment: There were attempts but none were successful